# Non-Java DocBook WebHelp output

Tags: extjs, docbook

Has anyone managed to get DocBook content output to webhelp that does not use a java applet? We are currently designing a web application that uses Ext JS and want to output the DocBook XML content into a format that can be used in parallel with our app (i.e. no Java applets).

It is the desire of our management that we stick with DocBook but we need a platform independent integrated help output (not .chm) that can be integrated with our webapp.

Any recommendations, suggestions and advice would be appreciated.

Laurie.

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering this after more than a year, but some may find this useful.

Under Google Summer of Code program, we created a WebHelp output format for DocBook. It does not rely on java-applets nor on frameset-based approach. It is pure css, JavaScript based so, it most probably fulfill your requirements. This is more search-engine friendly, as this does not rely on frame-sets. This is available with DocBook XSL from release 1.76.0 onwards.

Following links will give you a idea.

The demo is available here: http://snapshots.docbook.org/xsl/webhelp/docs/content/ch01.html The documentation for WebHelp is included in the demo.

Release notes for 1.76.1 is at: [DocBook WebHelp Project](http://blog.kasunbg.org/2010/08/docbook-webhelp-project.html)

SVN location: http://docbook.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/docbook/trunk/xsl/webhelp/

The proposal is at: [Proposal for WebHelp output for DocBook](http://blog.kasunbg.org/2010/04/proposal-web-help-output-for-docbook.html).

Sorry for the huge no. of links. Contact us on DocBook mailing list if you need further help. This is being actively maintained.

Comment: WebHelp is kind of frustrating. oLinks and dirs are broken, so need to fix them by your own. Customizing the XSL often breaks the search to don't work properly. In fact, its an really early beta...

Answer (score 1):

Adobe RoboHelp uses framesets to render the webhelp. Customizing the CSS itself is a huge pain. Add to that the unresponsive Adobe support. 
Also, the whole look and feel of your webhelp site would be very 1990s.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Adobe RoboHelp](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp/)? Fairly positive it's platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Im so glad we switched to Docbook.
We are now using the DocBook WebHelp Project developed by David Crammer and KasunBG.

This solves all our techpubs issue.

- Our docs are now tied to the source code in git
- Dev teams can propose patches to the docs
- We can now auto-generate the docs using continuous integration
- Not to mention the look and feel of the site.
- Our multiformat and multi-device publishing worries are resolved!